# Does the given C code has both syntax error and semantic error?

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Already, so many downvotes for this question. Is anyone reading it carefully, I didn't applied comma intentionally.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{   

      aloft a b ; // I have not applied comma intentionally 

      a = 4.00 ; b = 20.00;

      printf("%d %d",a,b);

      return 0;

}
```

I ran the above program and I got the following output:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:7:7: error: unknown type name 'aloft'
       aloft a b ;
       ^
prog.c:7:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'b'
       aloft a b ;
               ^
prog.c:9:7: error: 'a' undeclared (first use in this function)
       a = 4.00 ; b = 20.00;
       ^
prog.c:9:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
prog.c:9:18: error: 'b' undeclared (first use in this function)
       a = 4.00 ; b = 20.00;
                  ^
```

Clearly, a and b are undeclared as shown in the output, so it gives clear information that there is a semantic error.

But, I am not having a clear idea that is it syntax error or not ?

As the code suffers from the following output :

```
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'b'
```

**This shows that syntax is not properly encoded in the program. Does this means syntax error?**

Alternatively, I tried to run this program as:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{   
      typedef float aloft;

      aloft a b ;

      a = 4.00 ; b = 20.00;

      printf("%d %d",a,b);

      return 0;

}
```

But still the output shows B undeclared and no use of comma, ;, etc.

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:8:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'b'
       aloft a b ;
               ^
prog.c:8:15: error: 'b' undeclared (first use in this function)
prog.c:8:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
prog.c:10:7: error: 'a' undeclared (first use in this function)
       a = 4.00 ; b = 20.00;
       ^
```

**It is clear that semantic error is there. But, Is there syntax error ? If not, then how it passes the syntax analysis phase ?**

Comment: You forget a comma: `aloft a, b;`

Comment: `aloft a b ;` should be `aloft a, b ;`

Comment: Whoever, downvoted it , I made it intentionally

Comment: On purpose or not - what difference does it make how your compiler chooses to handle errors when there's more than one (or even when there's one for that matter)??? Also, please note that how your compiler handles errors is not something dictated by the C-language standard. In other words, every compiler implementation may choose to handle errors in a different manner, so there's no a single definite answer to your question.

Comment: @barakmanos, You may be a veteran in it. But I am just an amateur. I am experimenting by self made C codes that how does the error evolves .

Comment: @Willturner: No problem, I was just wondering why one would need to learn C via explicitly inserting errors in the code. This can only expand your knowledge in the behavior of your (specific) compiler. I don't see how it can help you with the C-language whatsoever. BTW, I did not down-vote you...

Comment: @barakmanos, I am not learning C. I am reading compilers and different types of errors. I read theoretically and now i am applying practically :)

Comment: OK, good luck with that :)

Answer (score 2):

There are both syntax and semantic errors.

The syntax error is missing comma between `a` and `b`.

The semantic error is wrong type name (`aloft` instead of `float`) for `a` and `b` variables.

The reason why you see both syntax and semantic errors is that compiler does the best job in order to recover and provide as much output as possible. Even though it might be misleading and produces lot more than it's really necessary to fix the root cause, in many cases it may help and avoids many runs of compiler to fix the issues sequentially.